# How to get result of Counter into two lists?

Tags: python

I am using `Counter` from `collections` to count the occurrence of some numbers. I am trying to put the numbers into one list and the count into another list.

The `Counter(array)` returns data that likes like `{(30: 2, 26: 2, 18: 2)}`. I would like for there to be two arrays, say `A[]` and `B[]`, where `A` would be `[30, 26, 18]` and `B` would be `[2, 2, 2]`.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `a, b = zip(*Counter(array).items())`

Comment: What went wrong with the attempt you tried? The `Counter` is, for all intents and purposes, just a dictionary here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just `zip` the `items` from the `dict` that `Counter` returns like,

```
>>> vals
[26, 26, 18, 18, 30, 30]
>>> import collections
>>> collections.Counter(vals)
Counter({26: 2, 18: 2, 30: 2})
>>> zip(*collections.Counter(vals).items())
[(26, 18, 30), (2, 2, 2)]
>>> a, b = zip(*collections.Counter(vals).items())
>>> a
(26, 18, 30)
>>> b
(2, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, so you can use the normal dictionary methods

```py
from collections import Counter

array = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
counter = Counter(array)
items = list(counter.keys())
counts = list(counter.values())
isinstance(counter, dict)  # True
```

Answer (score 0):

[Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is a spcialized dict. It has [keys()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) and [values()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) as well as [items()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)

```
from collections import Counter

c =Counter( {30: 2, 26: 2, 18: 77} )

a = list(c.keys())      # make a list from the keys view
b = list(c.values())    # make a list from the values


# or # decompose the list of key,value tuples
A, B = map(list,zip(*c.items()))    

print(a,b,A,B,sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
[30, 26, 18]   # a
[2, 2, 77]     # b
[30, 26, 18]   # A
[2, 2, 77]     # B
```

Doku:

- [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
- [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

Answer (score 0):

Use .items() to collect the keys and values:

```
from collections import Counter
d=['a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
l = Counter(d)
A=[k for k, v in l.items()]
print(A)

Result: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```